# Boolean in Angular app typescript file returns an error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to assign boolean in one of properties (**completed**) for object **todos**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todos',
  templateUrl: './todos.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todos.page.scss'],
})
export class TodosPage {
  todos = [
    {
      text: 'End frontend',
      completed: False
    },
    {
      text: 'Apple',
      completed: True
    },
    {
      text: 'Mango',
      completed: True
    }
  ]
}
```

But this code gives me:

```
Error: src/app/features/todos/pages/todos/todos.page.ts:12:18 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'False'.

12       completed: False
                    ~~~~~

Error: src/app/features/todos/pages/todos/todos.page.ts:16:18 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'True'.

16       completed: True
                    ~~~~

Error: src/app/features/todos/pages/todos/todos.page.ts:20:18 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'True'.

20       completed: True
```

How can i assign boolean to property so i could use this later for logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript uses lowercase `true`/`false` like Java/C#/... and not `True`/`False` like Python/Haskell/...

> A **Boolean** in Javascript is a primitive value that can be either `true` or `false`.
>
> — [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Boolean/JavaScript)